# Custom HTTP Message Converter Not Being Used, 415 Unsupproted Media Type

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a test application to achieve conversion from XML String to Employee object before being passed to the controller. I don't want to use JAXB converter because the purpose is to test Custom HTTP Message Converter which I am going to use in my actual use case that involves XML parsing using SAX parser and some complex rules.

Here are the key steps performed:

- **Creation of Employee.java Class** : Domain Object
- **Creation of EmployeeManagementController.java class** : Spring MVC Controller for Managing Employee
- **Creation of EmployeeConverter.java** : Custom Converter for Converting XML String to Employee Object.
- **Creation of employee-servlet.xml** : Spring Configuration file
- **Creation of web.xml** : The Deployment Descriptor

**Employee.java**

```
@Component
@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee{

@XmlElement(name="name")
String name;
@XmlElement(name="designation")
String designation;
@XmlElement(name="skill")
String skill;

public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
public String getDesignation() {
return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
this.designation = designation;
}
public String getSkill() {
return skill;
}
public void setSkill(String skill) {
this.skill = skill;
}

}
```

**EmployeeManagementController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/emp")
public class EmployeeManagementController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/add/employee", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="text/html")
    public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        System.out.println("Employee Name : "+employee.getName());
        System.out.println("Employee Designation : "+employee.getDesignation());
        System.out.println("Employee Skill : "+employee.getSkill());

    }


}
```

**EmployeeConverter.java**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Employee>{

    @Override
    protected Employee readInternal(Class<? extends Employee> arg, HttpInputMessage inputMsg) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String,String> paramMap = getPostParameter(inputMsg);
        BufferedReader file =  new BufferedReader(new StringReader(paramMap.get("xml")));
        Employee employee = null;
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            employee = (Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        if(type.getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Employee arg0, HttpOutputMessage arg1)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Map<String,String> getPostParameter(HttpInputMessage input) throws IOException{
        String payload = null;
        String[] params = null;
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input.getBody()));
        Map<String,String> paramMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

        String line="";
        while((line = buf.readLine())!=null){
            payload = payload+line;
        }

        if(payload.contains("&")){
            params = payload.split("&");
            for(String param : params){
                paramMap.put(param.split("=")[0],param.split("=")[1]);
            }
        }

        return paramMap;
    }


}
```

**employee-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

         <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> 

        <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

         <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters>
                <bean class="com.converter.EmployeeConverter"/>             
            </mvc:message-converters>
        </mvc:annotation-driven>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                    <entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
                    <entry key="htm" value="text/html"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html"/>
        </bean>

        <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">    
                <util:list id="beanList">
                    <ref bean="employeeConverter"/>       
                </util:list>
            </property>
        </bean>  -->

        <!-- <bean id="employeeConverter" class="com.converter.EmployeeConverter"/> -->



</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestConverter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

When I Use FireFox RestClient I get Response as : ***415 Unsupproted Media Type.***

I set the Content-Type and Accept header as text/xml in RestClient and pass the following XML string in the body as parameter:

```
xml=<employee><name>Jack</name><designation>Account Director</designation><skill>Commuication</skill></employee>
```

Can somebody help and let me know what changes are required? I have also tried to use `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` for registering the message converter.

Comment: I think you need to set `supportedMediaTypes` property in your converter. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/converter/AbstractHttpMessageConverter.html#setSupportedMediaTypes%28java.util.List%29

Comment: Thanks Pavel, Setting supported mediaType did work for me.

Comment: You are welcome... please accept Ralph's answer as he described that in more detail, pointed out the existence of `AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter` and also warn about overriding default configuration.

Comment: Now i changed the return type of the Controller method to @ResponseBody Employee and also added produces="application/json" attribute. I returned the employee object. But the response status received at the RestClient was 406 Not Acceptable, which happens if format of the response is different from what is suggested by the accept header of the request. But i have set the accept header in request using the RESTClient as application/json which is same as produces attribute of the controller method. I dont know why i am getting this response status.

Comment: don't check class type against string name in 'supports' method. use next expression instead:
 return clazz.equals(Employee.class);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1. Set Media Type**

Comparing your implementation with some `HttpMessageConverter` implementations provided by Spring (for example ´MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter´), shows that you missed to define the `supportedMediaTypes`.

The common way* of `HttpMessageConverter` that extends `AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T>` is to set the media type in the constructor, by using the super constructor `AbstractHttpMessageConverter.(MediaType supportedMediaType)`.

```
 public class EmployeeConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Employee> {
      public EmployeeConverter() {
            super(new MediaType("text", "xml", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      }
 }
```

BTW 1: you can also register more then one media type**

```
super(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
      MediaType.TEXT_XML,
      new MediaType("application", "*+xml"));
```

BTW 2: for xml conterter one should think extending from `AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter<T>`

**2. Register you Converter**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
       ...
       <bean class="com.example.YourConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

<strike>The major drawback of `<mvc:message-converters>` is, that this replace the default configuration, so you must also register all default `HttpMessageConverter` explicit.</strike>

To keep the default message convertes you need to use: `<mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">...`

- **used by the other implementations like MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter´*
- ***example take from `AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter<T>`*

Comment: Thats true Ralph ! the most important point to take is that custom converter replaces the default set of converters. I need to take care of this in my code or else it could be a greater problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: nice hint

Comment: If you don't mind, put that in your answer. I reached it by googling, so there will probably be many others.

Comment: XSD says, 
Element : message-converters
Configures one or more HttpMessageConverter types to use for converting "@RequestBody" method parameters and "@ResponseBody" method return values. Using this configuration element is optional. HttpMessageConverter registrations provided here will take precedence over HttpMessageConverter types registered by default. Also see the register-defaults attribute if you want to turn off default registrations entirely.

If I am not wrong, adding custom message converter does not remove default http message converters.

Comment: [And for the `register-defaults` usage in spring 4...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881212/what-is-the-equivalent-of-register-defaults-false-in-spring-4)