# What is the equivalent of register-defaults="false" in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I configure my custom message converter to have **`register-defaults="false"`** in a XML-less project with Spring 4?

```
<mvc:annotation-driven register-defaults="false">
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="myproject.MyCustomHttpMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Currently I have this `Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class TestDataConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Java Configuration as it is, is similar to the one with `register-defaults="false"` in XML Configuration. You don't need to do anything. But if you want to Register Defaults you would have to extend from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and add the last line specified in the below code snippet.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class TestDataConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(converter);
        super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(); // Have to call this explicitly to register Default Message Converters.
    }
}
```

Comment: @shazin, looks like `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters)` should be [taking the `converters` as a parameter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters-java.util.List-)

Comment: @NickGrealy Not all versions. http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/09/customizing-httpmessageconverters-with.html

Comment: @shazin, thanks, what spring version is that? (you're link doesn't tell me what version of spring it pertains to).

Answer (score 1):

It is true, what @shazin has written - that Java configuration from the first post is an equivalent to XML's `register-defaults="false"`.

However, if you need to get an equivalent to `register-defaults="true"` - as far as i'm aware - you could implement `extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` method in `WebMvcConfigurer` (or override it in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`) - like in an example below:

```
public class TestDataConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // your custom implementation
    }

}
```