# Spring adding ProtobufHttpMessageConverter to controllers without xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This should be really simple but i cannot figure how to add `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` for Spring Controllers while keeping default `HttpMessageConverters`.

I have setup client side (RestTemplate) but for every request i send there is **error 415**: content not supported.

Every example i have found so far refers to either Spring Boot or XML configuration, however neither of these work for me.

In the
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881212/what-is-the-equivalent-of-register-defaults-false-in-spring-4) about similar issue,
extending the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`  apparently removes default handlers.

It is stated to extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`  to keep default handlers, but given implementation doesn't work for Spring 4x as method call `super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters();` requires List of converters.

I have tried variantions on theme but neither seems to work:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan

public class RestServiceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    converters.add(new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter());

    // getMessageConverters().add(new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter());
    // super.configureMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
    super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me to add `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` while keeping default converters, without xml configuration ?

Comment: Override `extendMessageConverters` instead of `configureMessageConverters` and don't call `super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`. However what you have so far should work as it will add your custom one and the defaults. You already have the list of converters so I don't get that comment.

Comment: I have just managed to make this work by removing the 'EnableWebMVC' annotation, contrary to existing answer on the topic. Apparently the annotation imports configuration from 'WebMvcConfigurationSupport' and therefore override didn't kick in.

Comment: You are right... Instead of extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` you should have been extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and use `@EnableWebMvc`. The later imports `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (well actually `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`. Then it would be a simple matter of simply implementing the `extendMessageConverters` method.

Comment: If you put this in answer i will gladly accept it. We could use correct one on the topic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your approach you could make it work. However due to the fact that you extended `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and used `@EnableWebMvc` is isn't working. You are basically configuring web support twice now, as [`@EnableWebMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) is importing `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (actually `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`).

To make your current setup work remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RestServiceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter());
        super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

However there is a better way, instead of extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` you should extend [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) and implement the `extendMessageConverters` method instead of the `configureMessageConverters`.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RestServiceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `extendMessageConverters` method has been added in Spring 4.1.3 for earlier versions use the first method!