# consumes is working for application/json but not for text/plain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring,

I have a controller class as follows:

I am trying to set a oilCount value, so I do a POST/PUT request.

When  set content type as application/json, it is working fine, but when i set as text/plain it is not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value="testserver/config")
@Controller
public class TestServerConfigController {

    @RequestMapping(value="oilcount", method={RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public void setOilCount(@RequestBody Integer oilValue) throws Exception {
              //set the  oilvalue send as the response body

    }
}
```

Assuming that adding consumes might solve the problem, I added following to the code

```
@RequestMapping(value="testserver/config", consumes = {"text/plain", "application/json"}** )
@Controller
public class TestServerConfigController {

    @RequestMapping(value="oilcount", method={RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public void setOilCount(@RequestBody Integer oilValue) throws Exception {
              //set the  oilvalue send as the response body

    }
}
```

But still I am getting the same error

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `HttpMessageConverter` which can parse `text/plain` in the response body and convert it to a `Integer`.

Spring already provides an `HttpMessageConverter` that can parse `application/json`. If your response body contains JSON content that is a JSON number (which maps to a Java `Integer`), it can do the conversion for you. The same cannot be said for `text/plain`.

You need to implement your own `HttpMessageConverter` that performs this parsing and conversion and register it. Through Java configuration, you can use something like [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(List)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters-java.util.List-) to register an instance. XML configuration must have something similar.

Comment: Please let me know what changes i need to do in code to add the HttpMessageConverter

Comment: ok i will try the mentioned approach and get back with the results

Comment: can you point me to any spring samples which I can use for my reference, since i am a spring newbee

Comment: @user2604052 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349030/how-to-create-a-custom-http-message-converter-spring-mvc-3-1-2) is a XML example. Look for the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class and how to use it. There are tons of examples online.

Comment: please note that i am using spring 4.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

By default, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter supports application/json and application/*+json with UTF-8 character set. This can be overridden by setting the supportedMediaTypes property. I add my converter and it works for me:

```
@Component
class MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterWithTextPlainSupport(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) :
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper) {
    init {
        supportedMediaTypes = supportedMediaTypes + MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN
    }
}
```