# java: Spring @RequestBody and @ResponseBody not working with java.net

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-mvc

Here is my java.net client code

```
    URL server = new URL(serverUrl);
    URLConnection connection = server.openConnection();

    /* DoOutput flag is set to true to inform URL connection that we are
     * sending data out. The default behavior is false. This will change
     * the request from GET to a POST.
     */
    connection.setDoOutput (true);

    /* Setting the UseCaches to false allows the application "tunnel
     * through" and ignore the caches.
     */
    connection.setUseCaches (false);

    connection.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream" );

    ObjectOutputStream sendData = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    sendData.writeObject(packet);
    sendData.flush();
    sendData.close();

    ObjectInputStream recieveData = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    response =  (Serializable) recieveData.readObject();

    System.out.println(response);

    recieveData.close();
```

And this is my server code with spring to receive the request and send back response

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Serializable fileUploadHandler(@RequestBody FilePacket packet, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response){

    // handle request

    return "response";      
}
```

While running the code with above configuration, upon sending the request to server, I get Http error 415

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL:
```

I removed `@RequestBody` and replaced it with

```
FilePacket packet = (FilePacket) new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream()).readObject();
```

and the request part was good. But then after a request I got the 406

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL:
```

and so I replaced `@ResponseBody` with

```
new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()).writeObject("response");
```

and then everything was good.

I've used these annotations with ajax and they work like charm but with java.net , I'm getting unsupported media type (415) and not acceptable (406). Is spring not able to read the request and send proper response or I'm missing something here? Is there a way to make it work?

Note: The class `FilePacket` is `Serializable`, one of whose fields is of type `byte[]` which holds the file data.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses a collection of `HttpMessageConverter` instances to deserialize request bodies into arguments it will pass to your handler method.

Spring does not have a such a `HttpMessageConverter` which converts `application/octet-stream` to your custom `FilePacket` class. You could instead use `byte[]` and do the conversion yourself (or provide your own `HttpMessageConverter` to do it).

Spring uses the same tactic for `@ResponseBody`, using these same `HttpMessageConverter` instances for serializing an object returned to the response body. It has nothing built-in which uses Java Serialization. Note that for most, if not all, of these response types, your client needs to provide an explicit `Accept:` header to specify what it accepts.

Comment: @ares If it's convertible to a `String` yes, again assuming all headers are correct.

Comment: I created a custom MessageConverter [FtmMessageConverter](https://ideone.com/iWLDBe), but still I'm getting 415. How can I integrate this converter to my request handler. Also, I want to get the request as `FilePacket` but the response can be anything `Serializable`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @ares [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349030/how-to-create-a-custom-http-message-converter-spring-mvc-3-1-2) show how to register a converter through XML. There's a corresponding Java configuration through a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` or adapter. You might want two converters, one to read `FilePacket` and one to write `Serializable`.