# Intecepting Rest Controller responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a REST service using spring boot. My controller is annotated with `@RestController`. For debugging purposes I want to intercept the `ResponseEntity` generated by each of the controller methods (if possible). Then I wish to construct a new `ResponseEntity` that is somewhat based on the one generated by the controller. Finally the new generated `ResponseEntity` will replace the one generated by the controller and be returned as part of the response.

I only want to be able to do this when debugging the application. Otherwise I want the standard response generated by the controller returned to the client.

For example I have the controller

```
@RestController
class SimpleController

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getname")
    public NameObject categories()
    {
        return new NameObject("John Smith");
    }
}

class NameObject{
    private String name;
    public NameObject(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
}
```

This will generate the response:

```
{"name" : "John Smith"}
```

But I would like to change the response to include status info of the actual response e.g:

```
{"result": {"name" : "John Smith"}, "status" : 200 }
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet will probably be creating a custom `HttpMessageConverter` to intercept your response and wrap it in another object with the status code.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349030/how-to-create-a-custom-http-message-converter-spring-mvc-3-1-2

Answer (score 2):

The way I would try to achieve such a functionality is first by creating an Interceptor. And example can be found [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter)

Second, I would employ Spring profiles to ensure that interceptor is loaded only in profile that I needed it in. Detail [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). It's not exaclty debugging, but might do the trick.

Comment: Your first link goes to the same destination as your second one.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with spring AOP, something like:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ResponseEntityTamperer {
    @Around("execution(* my.package.controller..*.*(..))")
    public Object tamperWithResponseEntity(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
                  throws Throwable {
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
                             .getInputArguments().toString()
                             .contains("jdwp");

        if(isDebug && retVal instanceof ReponseEntity) {
            // tamper with the entity or create a new one
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

The "find out if we're in debug mode" code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778768/320220).